# Is there a way to use sql functions like min as values in where clause of mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, where-clause, min

i am having problem with the mysql statements... the answer is to get the name of city and length of city of min length from a table named station where ordered by alphabetically by city names i have tried some statements as described below.

`SELECT City, LENGTH(City) FROM Station ORDER BY City WHERE LENGTH(City) = MIN(LENGTH(City));`

I have also tried to use user defined varibales like below:

`SELECT @min := MIN(LENGTH(City)) FROM Station ORDER BY City;`

`SELECT City, LENGTH(City) FROM Station ORDER BY City WHERE LENGTH(City) = @min;`

Sample Output: Amo 3

it showing this error : check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE LENGTH(City) = @min'

But it's not working please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and note that you probably want CHAR_LENGTH for this.

Comment: I don't think you can use order by before where.

Comment: @Strawberry i don't understand what you are trying to say i have provided the code with sample output should i provide you with mysql table data because i am new here.

Comment: The accepted answer at the linked question seems self-explanatory to me :-(

Comment: @shazyriver i have tried to use order by after where but it's showing ERROR 1111 (HY000) at line 1: Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this solution. I can use complex sql statements to equalize the length of the city to the minimun length by using the sql statements below:

`SELECT City, LENGTH(City) FROM Station WHERE LENGTH(City) = (SELECT MIN(LENGTH(City)) FROM Station) ORDER BY City LIMIT 1;`